# Sort list based on a subset list (without nested loops)

Tags: python, string, loops, sorting

I'm trying to sort a long list of labels based on a master list, and am struggling to implement this efficiently. As the example below shows, I want to group together all items in the long list which share a common start to the string, then create a new list with these in the same order as the "master list".

With Python I'd normally try to vectorize and parallel process arrays, but this seems to work less well for arrays based on strings.

Here is my example and solution using nested loops:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']  # "master list"
labels = ['banana2', 'apple2', 'orange1', 'banana1', 'apple1', 'apple3']  # "long list"
new_list = []
for fruit in fruits:
    for label in labels:
        if fruit in label:
            new_list.append(label)
```

`print(new_list)` then returns

```
['apple2', 'apple1', 'apple3', 'banana2', 'banana1', 'orange1']
```

Can this be done without nested loops?

For an added bonus, I'd ideally like the labels to be sorted based on the final number in the string too, e.g. giving the result:  `['apple1', 'apple2', 'apple3', 'banana1', 'banana2', 'orange1']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another easy way:

```
import re

fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']  # "master list"
labels = ['banana2', 'apple2', 'orange1', 'banana1', 'apple10', 'apple3']  # "long list"

def normal_sort(text):
    return [int(c) if c.isdigit() else c for c in re.split('(\d+)', text)]

def func(x):
    x = " ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", x))
    return x

print(sorted(sorted(labels, key=func), key=normal_sort))
# ['apple2', 'apple3', 'apple10', 'banana1', 'banana2', 'orange1']
```

Comment: @jpp Thank you. I fixed that now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way, using [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) to derive sort order.

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
labels = ['banana2', 'apple2', 'orange1', 'banana1', 'apple1', 'apple3']

res = sorted(labels, key=lambda x: fruits.index(x[:-1]))

# ['apple2', 'apple1', 'apple3', 'banana2', 'banana1', 'orange1']
```

You can use a `tuple` as sort key too, combine with some regular expression to separate integers of any size.

```
import re

fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
labels = ['banana2', 'apple2', 'orange1', 'banana1', 'apple10', 'apple3']

def sorter(mystr, fruits):
    str_split = re.match(r'([a-z]+)([0-9]+)', mystr, re.I).groups()
    return (fruits.index(str_split[0]), int(str_split[1]))

res2 = sorted(labels, key=lambda x: sorter(x, fruits))

# ['apple2', 'apple3', 'apple10', 'banana1', 'banana2', 'orange1']
```

Comment: what if it's `apple10` in the list, or what if the digits go into the tens, hundreds, etc..?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to improve:

- You don't need `if fruit in label:`, you can just use `if fruit == label[0:len(fruit)]`, because you don't need the full substring search, only the beginning.
- You can sort `labels` first, so that when you find the first one, you can just add until the check fails and skip the rest, because then you're sure they'll not match any more. Obviously sorting has a cost, but it should still be more efficient than checking everything every time. You'll need a copy of it, so as not to lose you reference about how they were sorted initially.